# Travelling to Italy without my spouse who is a UK citizen

Tags: schengen-visas, uk-citizens

I am India citizen married to a UK national who has been issued a Schengen Visa from the Italian consulate as a spouse of a UK national. My husband was supposed to travel with me but now can’t. We have decided that I should still pursue the trip without him as I will be joining our friends there. Please can someone let me know if I will still be allowed to travel to the Schengen region with a valid Schengen Visa issued as a spouse of a EEA national but without my husband joining me there in person ?

Comment: Does the visa have an annotation mentioning your husband?

Comment: Hello, yes on the visa it says family. I managed o get hold of the consulate today and they said as long as I can prove I am a family member (marriage certificate, passport) then I should have no issues with border control. I am unconvinced.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the UK, the Schengen area does not issue a separate class of visa for family members of people who qualify for free movement.  Once you've got the Schengen visa, you can use it like a normal Schengen visa.

You could be accused of a fraudulent application, though, so if you can document the reason for your change of plans, or that the consulate told you that the visa was okay to use despite your change of plans, or (perhaps best) that you tried to apply for a new visa but the consulate told you not to, then you ought to be able to dispel any such suspicions.