# Travelling to EU without EU spouse

Tags: schengen-visas, eu, spouses

Me and wife were planned to travel to France to attend a wedding.

She is from the EU region and i am not, i apply for schengen visa as an EU spouse which recently is required of her to sign a letter saying that she will be travelling with me.

Now, something has come up and she will not be able to travel with me.

Will i be allowed to travel alone ?

regards
r

Comment: I believe someone else asked essentially the same question in the last couple of weeks, though I do not see it at the moment.  The answer is basically that you should be fine, but you should be prepared to show that your wife's plans changed after you submitted the visa application.

Comment: Found it: Possible duplicate of [Travelling to Italy without my spouse who is a UK citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137649/travelling-to-italy-without-my-spouse-who-is-a-uk-citizen)

Comment: thank you for that, however the new schengen visa has UE Familee in the remarks section, it is still a type C visa aswell.